# Is it possible to have a border be inset into an element, leaving a margin?

Tags: css, border

I want some of my divs to have a top border, but I want this border to be slightly inset into the element, leaving the top few pixels as-is, with the div content visible there.

Is there a way to do this? I am not looking for a js or jQuery solution.

In the picture below, I'd like the brown part to be a div, with a kind of 4px orange border that is inset OR two borders, one orange and one brown. It needs to be just on top of the element.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a diagram of what you want?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not exactly border, but CSS3 [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow) can be drawn inside the box with the original-color border outside:

```
#my_div { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: brown;
    padding: 10px;
    color: orange;
    border-top: 10px brown solid; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px  orange;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aprillion/ZRSCN/)

Comment: A great use of new technologies without having to resort to unnecessary elements. Although this won't work in browsers that don't support `box-shadow` but then, it's not related to content to it shouldn't matter too much :)

Comment: Great solution, thanks! The compatibility is another issue, but this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking can't be done with a single element because of the [box model standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), but it's trivial to do with two elements.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        What can I design fo
    </div>
</div>
```

Just give `.outer` padding on top and `.inner` can handle the border.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/NGbeB/

Comment: This was my workaround, indeed. Pity that it can't be done, and thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: it can be done with single element and CSS3, not sure about the browser compatibility though, so this approach is probably safer

Answer (score 0):

If the border is meant to go all the way around the element and not just a specific side, you can use outline for this purpose:

http://tinker.io/95978

```
h1 {
    background: #CCC;
    outline: 2px solid;
    outline-offset: -8px;
    padding: 10px;
}

<h1>I like borders</h1>
```

However, the outline-offset property isn't supported in any version of IE.

You could also use a pseudo element to hold the border, which would allow you to specify the border only on specific sides.

http://tinker.io/95978/1

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
    background: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
}

h1:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 2px solid;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
}
```

Should work in IE8+ and pretty much any other browser.